# How to get Typescript files to hit breakpoints in the original file, not in Dynamic tab?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Before upgrading to Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 2 RC, when I add a breakpoint in a Typescript file, the breakpoint will hit in the original Typescript file.  However, after the upgrade, when the breakpoint hits, a new tab in Visual Studio opens with the title  and the code pauses in the dynamic file instead of the original typescript file.  How can I make the breakpoints hit in the original Typescript file again?  I have marked the typescript file properties to be "Do not copy", so I don't understand why it is being considered as Dynamic?  Nothing is being generated on the fly here?

Comment: Take a look at this link -- this issue is reported on TypeScript project page: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2477

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a .map file along w/ a .js file?  When you compile your Typescript you need to use the compiler option of -sourcemap

This will create a .map file that VS2013 uses to know how to map the js file to your typescript file.

so in your folder you should see:

- file.ts
- file.js
- file.js.map

Comment: Yes, I do have -sourcemap enabled and I do see a .map file being generated.  The breakpoint actually is hitting in the Typescript file code, so I think the map is working.  But the Typescript file that is breaking is the "Dynamic" version, not the one in the project.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Dynamic" version.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, when you are debugging a dynamically loaded file, it opens up on the right hand side in a separate tab with this in its filename: [Dynamic].  There are the files that appear under "Script Documents" in your Solution Explorer when you're running the web app and they disappear as soon as you stop debugging.

Comment: What does it matter if its using the Dynamic version or your original version?  Your still debugging the same file right?

Comment: Well, your changes to the Dynamic version will not be saved.  In any case, I uninstalled update 2 RC and got my original behavior back.  Thanks.