# Why does Debugging of TypeScript in VS 2015 makes a dynamic file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, source-maps

I am currently working on a project with AngularJS, ASP.NET and TypeScript. The problem is to get TypeScript debugging working with the original file in VS 2015. Source-maps are created and loaded from the Browser, and the breakpoint hits, but not in the original file, but in a dynamic file, which has the same code as the original. It's very painful, because in the dynamic files, you don't have any data tooltips. I have installed the latest TypeScript MSBuild (2.2.1) from NuGet and the transpiling step is working. My source-maps, JS and TS files are on the same project hierarchy in VS and the source-maps look like this:

```
{"version":3,"file":"LinksController.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["LinksController.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"..."}
```

My hierarchy on the browser is vstatic/[MD5Hash of file]/[jsFile]. I have searched a lot in the web, tried something like changing the 'checking for new versions of stored pages' option in IE, that didn't work. I couldn't find any solution regarding TypeScript. I use IIS, IE11 and VS 2015 Update 3.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you use the IE browser or other browsers? http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/05/27/TypeScript-debugging-in-Visual-Studio-with-IE-Chrome-and-Firefox-using-Source-Maps.aspx

Comment: I use Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: this issue was reported to the typescript team before, other community members also asked this issue before even if it was about the VS2013:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067947/how-to-get-typescript-files-to-hit-breakpoints-in-the-original-file-not-in-dyna

Comment: Do you know any way to enable data tooltips in dynamic files? In JS it's working, but not in TS.